# For postgresql, from a single table with id, name, and parent column, how to recursively put child lines into a child column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

if my postgres table menu_item has column id, name, and parent, and have 4 rows of data as

| id | name | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mi_1 |  |
| 2 | mi_2 | 1 |
| 3 | mi_3 | 2 |
| 4 | mi_4 | 2 |

how to make a query that returns

| id | name | children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mi_1 | `[{id:2, name:'mi_2',children: [{id:3, name:'mi_3'},{id:4, name:'mi_4'}]}]` |

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE menu_tree AS (
  SELECT 
    id, name, parent, 1 AS level
  FROM 
    menu_item mi
  WHERE 
    parent IS NULL  -- Select top-tier parents
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    mi.id, mi.name, 
    mi.parent,mt.level + 1 AS level
  FROM 
    menu_item mi
  INNER JOIN 
    menu_tree mt ON mi.parent = mt.id
) 
 SELECT id, name, parent, jsonb_agg(children) AS children
FROM (
  SELECT id, name, parent,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM menu_item mi WHERE mi.parent = mt.id) 
        THEN (SELECT jsonb_agg(child) 
                FROM (SELECT id, name, parent
                          FROM menu_tree 
                          WHERE parent = mt.id
                ) child
              )
        ELSE '[]'::jsonb
        END AS children
  FROM menu_tree mt
) t
GROUP BY id,name, parent;
```

I expect the result to be just 1 line that contains the hierarchy in the children column, but this returns all 4 lines, each drills down only 1 level to its immediate descendant.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a solution for this specific data structure, 1 child and
> multiple grandchildren per parent.

Your recursive cte is good, I added a parent_tree to serve as a final group id when building the jsonb :

```
WITH RECURSIVE menu_tree AS (
  SELECT 
    id, name, parent, 1 AS level, id as parent_tree
  FROM 
    menu_item
  WHERE 
    parent IS NULL  -- Select top-tier parents
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    mi.id, mi.name, mi.parent, mt.level + 1 AS level, mt.parent_tree
  FROM 
    menu_item mi
  INNER JOIN 
    menu_tree mt ON mi.parent = mt.id
)
select max(case when parent is null then id end) as id,
       max(case when parent is null then name end) as name,
       json_build_array(
         json_build_object(
            'id', max(case when level = 2 then id end),
            'name', max(case when level = 2 then name end),
            'children', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', id, 'name', name)) filter (where level = 3 )
         ) 
       ) as children
from menu_tree
group by parent_tree;
```

Results :

```
id  name    children
1   mi_1    [{"id" : 2, "name" : "mi_2", "children" : [{"id": 3, "name": "mi_3"}, {"id": 4, "name": "mi_4"}]}]
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fHBlAw29)

Comment: I realized this will omit all but the last tier 2 item, and add the last tier 3 item to it as child, even though the tier 3 one may not belong to it. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gurwa_Tb)